# DistributionFitTest with WeightedData?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

My problem is related to statistical testing with weighted data. I have a data sample and I assume that a part of the data follows a specific distribution (Pareto). So I fit my data to a distribution by using `EstimatedDistribution` and in turn I obtain a p-value related to this fit according to different statistical tests (Cramer-Von Mises, Kolmogorov-Smirnov and possibly others).

Everything goes well as long as I do not include weights (I really know it works, since I have replicated my results in another software package...).

When including weights by using the function `WeightedData` I run into problems. `EstimatedDistribution` still works well on `WeightedData` (again results are replicated in another package), but the `DistributionFitTest` does not work any longer.

When trying to apply `DistributionFitTest` on `WeightedData` I get an error message of the following form:

> "rctnln: The argument [my weighted data object] at position 1 should be a rectangular array of real numbers with length greater than the dimension of the array."

I got the intuition behind these error message and intensely searched for an appropriate work-around or alternative Function, but could not find any suitable tools.

Could anybody help me out on this?

Comment: A little bit of code to reproduce this: `data = {8, 3, 5, 4, 9, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3};
w = {0.15, 0.09, 0.12, 0.10, 0.16, 0., 0.11, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09};
wd = WeightedData[data, w]; DistributionFitTest[wd]`. Seems like `DistributionFitTest` wasn't updated when `WeightedData` was introduced. However, `DistributionFitTest[EmpiricalDistribution[w -> data]]` doesn't work either and `EmpiricalDistribution` was introduced a version ago.

Comment: I also tried the variant you suggest (i.e. using DistributionFitTest[EmpiricalDistribution[w -> data]]) when I was still using version 8. Basically it was the same issue as far as I remember. Another variant I tried was to integrate a RandomVariate to draw form the empirical distribution and test this artificial data against the distribution. This worked out well, but I was unsure whether this really represents what I am trying to do...

Comment: You may consider reporting this at support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I got the following comment from Wolfram: "Unfortunately, DistributionFitTest does not currently support
WeightedData objects. Our developers are aware of user interest in this feature, and are working to include it in a future version of Mathematica.

On your behalf, I've filed your comments with our development team for their review as they move forward.

We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thankyou ...." So there will be no solution to my problem on this front - has anyone a suggestion for an appropriate work-around?

Comment: How did the weights come about?  Did you sample some parts of more intensely than others?  Are some observations estimated more precisely than others?  How one might appropriately use weights should start with a definition of what the weights are.

Answer (score 5):

`DistributionFitTest[data]` test the hypothesis that the `data` came from normal distribution.

This is typically done by testing if the empirical CDF is close enough to the CDF, expected under the null hypothesis.

The first visual test is to inspect [QQ-plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot), implemented in Wolfram Language as [QuantilePlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantilePlot.html).

Consider synthetic data:

```
refD = NormalDistribution[1, 2];
baseD = LogisticDistribution[1, 2];
data = RandomVariate[baseD, 10^3];
weights = PDF[refD][data]/PDF[baseD][data];
wd = WeightedData[data, weights];
```

Visualize QQ-plot against normal:

```
qd = QuantilePlot[wd, NormalDistribution[1, 2]]
```

[image: parametric plot of empirical quantile vs.]

The fit is pretty good here, and many tests assess the goodness of fit by computing some distance between these two lines and assessing whether the so obtained number is typical under the null.

For instance, we can compute [Anderson-Darling test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#The_single-sample_test) as follows:

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[wd];

ad$test = 
 NExpectation[(CDF[ed, x] - CDF[refD, x])^2/(CDF[refD, 
      x] SurvivalFunction[refD, x]), x~Distributed~refD]

(* Out[13]= 0.000747316 *)
```

or [Cramer-von-Mises test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion):

```
cvm$test = 
 NExpectation[(CDF[ed, x] - CDF[refD, x])^2, x~Distributed~refD]

(* Out[14]= 0.000128502 *)
```

or [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test):

```
ks$test = MaxValue[Abs[CDF[ed, x] - CDF[refD, x]], x]

(* Out[15]= 0.0203543 *)
```

Since the sample size is rather large for this dataset, we might be OK with using the asymptotic distributions to compute the p-value. It is less clear what to do with small datasets. I would expect the test statistics' distribution to depends on the actual weight vector.

The safest route would be to use Monte-Carlo method, which computes test statistics on samples from the null to determine if the test statistics computed on data is typical. The problem is that sampling does not give you `WeightedData`, hence we might be comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @whuber If you have comments, or references on the matter, I would greatly appreciate it if you shared them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `EmpiricalDistribution[]` does not generate a PDF function, only a CDF. A work around could be to create an un-weighted data set out of your data. It's sub-optimal to say the least, and you may run out of memory on some data sets before getting your answer, but it works.

`Flatten[ConstantArray @@ # & /@ Transpose[{data, Ceiling[100*w]}]]`

Note that I used 100 as the multiplier since your weights were all in hundredths. Also, weight 0. for InputData 0 makes no sense. You have an element which has no weight, e.g. is not possible in the data. Just remove it. Or set frequency to something very small.

Comment: I am really not sure why you believe PDF is of any relevance here. Moreover, `PDF` is defined: `PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[{0.8, 0.2} -> {1, 2}], {0, 1, 2, 3}]` outputs `{0, 0.8, 0.2, 0}`.